# Is "What are resources you'd wish you had seen when starting out?" too subjective/off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I'd like to ask a question about resources (like blog posts, advice, etc) that would be useful for newer Magic: The Gathering players looking to learn more about the game. (I have one player specifically in mind but I want to keep it generic in the spirit of StackExchange, of course.)

I would imagine it would be a community wiki like [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c).

I've read [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), but I'm still not entirely sure if it would be in the former category.

I think it would be great if there was a resource for new players to find information about intermediate M:tG concepts like card advantage, last responsible moment, signalling in draft, etc, but I'm not sure if everyone would agree if StackExchange is a good place for it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating a question with the intent that it will be community wiki it is unlikely to be a successful question.  In fact I tend to close any question that has "this should be CW" or the like so it's great that you are asking in meta.

That said, I think the best approach is to figure out how to phrase a great subjective question to extract the information that you are looking for.  Think about what awesome answers to your question would look like.  It's unlikely to be an endless list of answers that each contain a link to one blog or column somewhere.  That leads to people voting on the link instead of the answer and quickly shifts into the "bad subjective" side of things.

Ideally you'd like an answer that contained something like this (forgive the lack of specifics, I don't keep up with Magic anymore)

> First, read this tutorial series, it's five years old so keep in mind that some of the example cards might not be available any more but the series is still the best way for a beginner to get up to speed fast.
>
> Then subscribe to a few blogs
>
> 1. Blog A updates every day with all the latest info about the current Magic scene.  You'll learn about upcoming sets, what's hot and what's not.
> 2. Blog B updates weekly or so.  Very deep strategical posts.  A beginner probably can't follow everything but will learn a ton.  This guy is a top tournament player and really knows his stuff
> 3. Blog C updates a few times a month erratically with really cool interesting deck suggestions.  They don't always pan out in tournament play but they explore interesting mechanics and are usually great decks to bust out with when playing with your friends.
> 4. Also, check out these two forums, the first is the largest  home of MtG players on the web, the second is smaller but a lot Of judges hang out there, if you have a tricky rules question, it is the place to ask it.

When you get an answer like that, all linked up, you have a good idea that the answerer probably knows his stuff.  If the answer is a link to a blog, the answerer might just have googled it right before posting the answer.